# Silverlight - How to post data to custom columns?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, app.xaml

I've got an app that I'm coding in Silverlight, and I need to post data to a datagrid. When I customize the datagrid and name each of the columns that I need, nothing posts appears when I click the button that would add the data. If I leave the columns undeclared, then the data posts, but the columns get named oddly and the spacing is also odd.

So, how do I post data to a specific column?

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Sootah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't bind columns with values.
Take a look to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/03/27/defining-columns-for-a-silverlight-datagrid.aspx) and [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tirthacs/140/Default.aspx) links.
It must solve your problem.